# Mostrando dados ao digitar

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso mostrar duas informações quando o usuário digitar o valor da comissão, no caso as informações que deveria mostrar seria `IR` e `Valor líquido`.

Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar `1.200,00`, no label `IR` apareceria `18,00%` (1.200 x 1,5%) e no label `Valor líquido` o total líquido (1.200 - 18) que no caso daria `1.182,00`.

Acredito que teria que montar alguma função em javascript, mas sou leigo com essa linguagem, ou se existir alguma outra forma, toda ajuda será bem vinda.

Obs. a intenção é somente mostras os dois valores IR e Valor Líquido sem precisar salvar nada, pois o que preciso salvar mesmo seria o valor da comissão.

Meu código:

```
<form method="post"action="processa.php">
    <label>Valor comissão:</label>
    <input type="text" name="valor_comissao">

    <label>IR:</label>
    <input type="text">

    <label>Valor Líquido:</label>
    <input type="text">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso usando o `keyup` no input assim:

```js
const [valor, ir, liquido] = [...document.querySelectorAll('form input')];

/* ou em browsers antigos:
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form input');
var valor = inputs[0];
var ir = inputs[1];
var liquido = inputs[2];
*/

function formatar$(nr) {
  return nr.toLocaleString('pt-BR');
}

valor.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var nr = Number(this.value);
  var _ir = nr * 1.5 / 100;
  ir.value = _ir + '%';
  liquido.value = formatar$(nr - _ir);
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="processa.php">
  <label>Valor comissão:</label>
  <input type="text" name="valor_comissao">

  <label>IR:</label>
  <input type="text">

  <label>Valor Líquido:</label>
  <input type="text">

  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas precisa importar alguma biblioteca para usar essa função? não consegui executar a função aqui..kk

Comment: @SmokeRohden não precisas de nenhuma biblioteca, é tudo JavaScript nativo. Se não consegues pôr a funcionar cria um jsFiddle com um exemplo que eu ajudo. Mas como teste podes colocar o JavaScript depois do HTML na página.

Comment: Até dava para fazer a criação das variáveis dos `inputs` com *Destructuring*

Comment: Entendi. coloquei no final deu certo!

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio valeu mesmo

Comment: @Isac sim, ficava mais limpo `const [valor, ir, liquido] = [...document.querySelectorAll('form input')];`